# Yii bootstrap custom login page

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, authentication, yii, themes

I installed a bootstrap theme for my yii application to be displayed on its login page.
How do I pass the information entered in these forms to the variables in `login.php`?

Also, how do I make the "Sign In" button in the theme to call the "Sign in" button in the `login.php`?

These are the forms in the bootstrap theme:

```
          <div class="clearfix">
            <input type="text" placeholder="username">
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix">
            <input type="password" placeholder="password">
          </div>

          <button class="btn primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
```

These are the forms that yii would display with its default theme in login.php:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for Yii best practice. Dont use login.php file instead use controller/action and in that action define your login logic like this: 
Login View file

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'login-form',
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
        ),
        )); ?>
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'username'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>
  <div class="row buttons">
  <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>
```

And this is your controller action:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
  $model=new LoginForm;
   if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
           $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
           if($model->validate() && $model->login()){
             //Your Logic//  
            }
      $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
                    'action'=>array('login.php')
                )); ?>
```

Normally Yii calls an action on a controller. Do you know the basics of Yii?